# How to move an array in JQuery into Perl

Tags: jquery, arrays, perl

I'm looking for a way to move the numeric values in an array collected using JQuery into a new array for Perl to pick up. Is this possible and is there a preferred method?

```
JQuery Array: addVssID 
Hash array: $self->input->vssID
```

- addVssID has the values (1, 11, 25) to represent checkboxes that have been checked in an HTML form. This collection/calculation is triggered when a SAVE button is clicked.
- Elsewhere in the program $self->input has been newly created to hold various pieces of vendor information that Perl later processes and saves to a MySQL database. I'm tailing the values in a log file, and don't see my expected results when I use DUMPER($self) in my Perl, though I can see other values populated.
- I'm basically looking at existing legacy code, copy/edit it for my own needs, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my JSON: To be completely honest, I don't really understand how this works.

```
var ShippingInput = $('<input type="hidden" name="Shipping" />');     
$ShippingInput.val(JSON.stringify(getShipping()));
$form.append($ShippingInput);
```

On the other end in Perl, I have this waiting to catch the results:

```
my $Shipping = [];
eval { $Shipping = JSON::from_json($self->input->{'vendor'}->{'Shipping'});
};
```

Ultimately I want to move the array values into a MySQL table. The other option is to push the array into the MySQL table and pull it out into Perl for processing. I don't know if this changes anything, but we also have Template Toolkit available.

UPDATE/SOLUTION:
Taking the JSON route, I took the dynamic value from the checkbox (value='Shipping_###'), strip off the text and add the number to array. I'm still shakey on how JSON/JQUERY works, but here is the get function and it seems to be working:

```
function getShipping() {
// called onSave from submitForm()
var shipping = [];

$('.Shipping').each(function(i, Shipping) {
    shipping.push($(Shipping).attr('id').replace('Shipping_', ''));
});
return shipping;
```

}

Comment: @Barmar: I'm new to JQuery. Can you be more specific on what I'm looking for in regards to JASON encoding?

Comment: @Vongrats - JSON is not JQuery specific. It's a standard data structure format for JavaScript. Google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. As Barmar indicated, collect the whole set of data (using jQuery) into a single JSON datastructure. Then serialize (encode) it into a string, and pass that string as a POST parameter to your Perl web backend code. In Perl, decode it using `JSON` module (which will be able to build a Perl datastructure from JSON one, mapping it the same way).
2. Create a set of input fields (hidden or not, based on your webapp). Then read them in Perl, and make the data structure by hand.

   It's hard to provide more specific help since you didn't provide specific example code to work with